# Could not map two array using JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I could not map two array of json data as per key value using JavaScript. My code is below:

```
 var userdata=[{'email':'a@gmail.com','name':'Rajj'},{'email':'b@gmail.com','name':'Rajesh'}];
        var userdata1=[{'email':'a@gmail.com','address':'rasukgarh'}];
        var finalArr=[];
        userdata.map(item => {
              userdata1.map(item1 => {
                if(item.email==item1.email){
                  finalArr.push(Object.assign(item, item1));
                }else{
                  finalArr.push(Object.assign(item, item1));
                }
              })
            })
            console.log('all Data',finalArr);
      }
```

Here my requirement is if same email id is present in both array then the additional data of second array will merge with first one. If 1st array has some data and based on the `email value` no data is present inside second array then in hat case only first array data will push to resultant array. Here my expected output is.

```
finalArr=[{'email':'a@gmail.com','name':'Rajj','address':'rasukgarh'},{'email':'b@gmail.com','name':'Rajesh'}]
```

But in my case I could not get like this.

Comment: Also remove the 'else{finalArr.push(Object.assign(item, item1));};'

Comment: Then only matched values are coming.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean

Comment: I need if email is matched for both array then both array data will merge otherwise what ever the data are in one single array that will push to finalArr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create new array and `find()` to find objects with same email in second array and `Object.assign()` to create copy of object and assign objects from second array.

```js
var userdata=[{'email':'a@gmail.com','name':'Rajj'},{'email':'b@gmail.com','name':'Rajesh'}];
var userdata1=[{'email':'a@gmail.com','address':'rasukgarh'}]

var result = userdata.map(function(e) {
  var find = userdata1.find(a => a.email == e.email);
  return Object.assign({}, e, find)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var userdata = [{ 'email': 'a@gmail.com', 'name': 'Rajj' }, { 'email': 'b@gmail.com', 'name': 'Rajesh' }];
    var userdata1 = [{ 'email': 'a@gmail.com', 'address': 'rasukgarh' }];
    userdata.map(function(item) {
        userdata1.map(function(item1) {
            if (item.email == item1.email) {
                // modify the original userdata array item
                Object.assign(item, item1);
            }
        })
    })
    console.log(userdata);
```